# RowSums NA + NA gives 0

Tags: r

I'll just understand a (for me) weird behavior of the function `rowSums`. Imagine I have this super simple dataframe:

```
a = c(NA, NA,3)
b = c(2,NA,2)
df = data.frame(a,b)
df
   a  b
1 NA  2
2 NA NA
3  3  2
```

and now I want a third column that is the sum of the other two. I cannot use *simply* `+` because of the `NA`:

```
df$c <- df$a + df$b
df
   a  b  c
1 NA  2 NA
2 NA NA NA
3  3  2  5
```

but if I use `rowSums` the rows that have `NA` are calculated as 0, while if there is only one `NA` everything works fine:

```
df$d <- rowSums(df, na.rm=T)
df
   a  b  c  d
1 NA  2 NA  2
2 NA NA NA  0
3  3  2  5 10
```

am I missing something?

Thanks to all

Comment: I was wondering why no one had answered `base::psum`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option with `rowSums` would be to get the `rowSums` with `na.rm=TRUE` and multiply with the negated (`!`) `rowSums` of negated (`!`) logical matrix based on the NA values after converting the rows that have all NAs into NA (`NA^`)

```
rowSums(df, na.rm=TRUE) *NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df))
#[1]  2 NA 10
```

Comment: This is a fun hack: `NA^0 == 1`.

Comment: you should add this as an answer to the linked question

Answer (score 6):

Because

```
sum(numeric(0))
# 0
```

Once you used `na.rm = TRUE` in `rowSums`, the second row is `numeric(0)`. After taking `sum`, it is 0.

If you want to retain `NA` for all `NA` cases, it would be a two-stage work. I recommend writing a small function for this purpose:

```
my_rowSums <- function(x) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) x <- as.matrix(x)
  z <- base::rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  z[!base::rowSums(!is.na(x))] <- NA
  z
  }

my_rowSums(df)
# [1]  2 NA 10
```

This can be particularly useful, if the input `x` is a data frame (as in your case). `base::rowSums` would first check whether input is matrix or not. If it gets a data frame, it would convert it into a matrix first. Type conversion is in fact more costly than actual row sum computation. Note that we call `base::rowSums` two times. To reduce type conversion overhead, we should make sure `x` is a matrix beforehand.

For @akrun's "hacking" answer, I suggest:

```
akrun_rowSums <- function (x) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) x <- as.matrix(x)
  rowSums(x, na.rm=TRUE) *NA^!rowSums(!is.na(x))
  }

akrun_rowSums(df)
# [1]  2 NA 10
```

Comment: mm ok.. But what if I want to keep NA also in the third column?

Comment: This will probably be a 2 step process. For example, `df$new <- rowSums(df, na.rm=T); is.na(df$new) <- rowSums(is.na(df)) == length(df)`